# TreeGrid extension for DataTables - get values of selected rows

Tags: javascript, datatables

I found a TreeGrid extension for DataTables:

https://homfen.github.io/dataTables.treeGrid.js/

but when I include a button to read the selected rows:

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
        select:true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Alert selected',
                action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
                    var data = table.rows({
                        selected: true
                    }).data().toArray();
                    
                    var i;
                    var text = new Array();
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    text.push(data[i].name);
                       
                    }
                    alert("you selected: " + text.join(",") );
                    console.log("text---" + text.join(","));

                }
            }
        ]
```

the extension behaves oddly:

- if I select a parent all underlying the children are no longer selected.

Does anyone know how I can get the selected rows in another way?

Comment: It's possible that the issue here may be related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67570767/12567365) about Tree Grid. If that other issue can be resolved, perhaps this one will also be resolved.

Comment: I describe here an odd behaviour when i add code to read the selected values. I am not sure if this is the proper way to do so.

Comment: Same comment here as I made in your other question. I can use `console.log( table.rows( { selected: true } ).toArray() );` with no problem - but that may not work for you, because I cannot recreate the problem you describe.