# TreeGrid extension for DataTables - how to get a checkbox added after name?

Tags: datatables

I found a TreeGrid extension for DataTables:

https://homfen.github.io/dataTables.treeGrid.js/

but instead of the name I would like to add a column between name and position and place a checkbox here.

However when I do this e.g.:

```
var columns = [
                {
                    title: '',
                    target: 0,
                    className: 'treegrid-control',
                    data: function (item) {
                        if (item.children) {
                            return '<span>+<\/span>';
                        }
                        return '';
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Name',
                    target: 1,
                    data: function (item) {
                        return item.name;
                    }
                },
                {
                    defaultContent: '',
                     target: 2,
                    className: 'select-checkbox',
                    function(item) {
                        return item;
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Position',
                    target: 3,
                    data: function (item) {
                        return item.position;
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Office',
                    target: 4,
                    data: function (item) {
                        return item.office;
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Extn.',
                    target: 5,
                    data: function (item) {
                        return item.extn;
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Start date',
                    target: 6,
                    data: function (item) {
                        return item.start;
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Salary',
                    target:7,
                    data: function (item) {
                        return item.salary;
                    }
                }
            ];
```

I get an extra column but when checking the parent does not select all underlying children rows.

Anyone have an idea how to establish this?

Edit: updated the columns definition.

When I add a button to read the selected values e.g.:

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
        select:true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Alert selected',
                action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
                    var data = table.rows({
                        selected: true
                    }).data().toArray();
                    
                    var i;
                    var text = new Array();
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    text.push(data[i].name);
                       
                    }
                    alert("you selected: " + text.join(",") );
                    console.log("text---" + text.join(","));

                }
            }
        ]
```

the table starts to behave oddly for example: the selection of underlying children stops.

Comment: I can't recreate the problem. When I check a parent checkbox, all the child checkboxes are also selected, down through the hierarchy. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Side note: When you use the `columns` option, the `target` option has no effect - it is ignored. Use `columnDefs` if you want to use `target`. That is not needed here - and if you changed `columns` to `columnDefs` you would see that `target: 2` is missing from your code.

Comment: I do see some inconsistencies in how child selected records behave when I expand/collapse their parents. For example a single child will still be reported as "selected" even when you collapse & re-expand the parent: at which point the child will no longer be highlighted (and the checkbox will no longer be checked). So, even though there is "one record selected" - there are no records highlighted.

Comment: but how can I get read whichs rows are selected?

Comment: Like I say, I cannot recreate your problem, so I cannot tell you how to fix it. When I use the following code in my button action, it works correctly for me: `console.log( table.rows( { selected: true } ).toArray() );`. This gives me an array containing the indexes of all selected records (parents and children). Using those indexes I can access each record. But this may not work _for you_, of course. If you can provide a [mre], that may help.